# What is the solution of the non-linear differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, transformation, nonlinear-analysis

Suppose that we $y(\cdot)$ is a decreasing and continuously differentiable function with respect to $x$ s.t. it holds

$$(\alpha-x)y^{'}(x)-\beta y(x)y^{'}(x)-y(x)=0$$
that is a non-linear differential equation, whera $x\neq\alpha$ and $\beta\in\mathbb{R}/\{0\}$. Can we solve this by using some kind of a transformation?

Comment: The de is homogeneous

Comment: Yes it should be possible. You can write it as $y'[ (\alpha - x) - \beta y ] = y$ so if you define $z = \beta y - (\alpha - x) $ you should be able to get a simpler ODE for $z$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(\alpha-x)y^{'}(x)-\beta y(x)y^{'}(x)-y(x)=0$$
i suppose that both $ \alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants.

Note that $(yx)'=xy'+y$:
$$\alpha y'(x)-\beta y(x)y'(x)-(xy'+y(x))=0$$
And $(y^2)'=2y'y$:
$$\alpha y'(x)-\dfrac 12\beta (y^2)'-(xy)'=0$$
Integrate.

$$\alpha y-\dfrac 12\beta y^2-xy=C$$

If $\alpha$ is a function of $x$ (not constant) then this won't work. It will then depend on the kind of function $\alpha(x)$ is.

Comment: What is the family of $\alpha(x)$ functions that gives a solution in closed form? Is for instance the family of quadratic funtions?

Comment: Is $\alpha$ a constant ? @HungerLearn

Comment: Yes it is, but since you mention it, in case this is not a constant, what is the thoery behind it? I would like to know, becasue you mention it. That's all!

Comment: I mean, where have you seen something like that?

Comment: I just mentioned it because I had to made the supposition that $\alpha$ is constant otherwise the solution I posted is not valid. but not sure you will find a closed form even for $\alpha =x^2$ for example. @HungerLearn

Comment: Ok! Thank you! It was very simple after all...

Comment: You're welcome @HungerLearn

Comment: Well, I have some question here. If someone for this family of functions, that is:
$$\alpha y-\frac{\beta}{2}y^2-xy=C$$ wants to find the solution of $y(x)$, then it is sufficient to take the FOC, with respect to $x$, isn't it? Namely, 
$$y(x)=\frac{\alpha-x}{\beta}$$

Comment: No its a square of y use $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab$ take the root and find y @HungerLearn

Comment: Well, what about the constant?

Comment: Transform the left side such that you have the form $(y+f(x))^2=g(x)$ than take the root and express y as a function of c @HungerLearn

Comment: If i am not mistaken, you mean that 
$$|y-\frac{\alpha-x}{\beta}|=\sqrt{\left(\frac{\alpha-x}{\beta}\right)^2-\frac{2}{\beta}C}$$

Comment: Yes @HungerLearn that's what I meant. looks good.

Comment: I need to privide the domain of $x$ also but I was bored to write it down! Thank you for everything!

Comment: Note that you can write $K=-2c/b$ since it's just a constant @HungerLearn You 're welcome take care.

Comment: Well, since i can not do any other question in maths.stockexchange, I have dealt with a similar kind od this non-linear d.e, that is
$$-xy^{'}(x)+\alpha y^{'}(x)-\beta y(x) y^{'}(x)=0$$
i.e. it misses your last term that is $-y(x)$. To solve it I add the term $-y(x)$ and my solution is
$$-xy(x)+\alpha y(x) -\frac{\beta}{2}y^2(x)=-\int y(x)dx + C$$
where $C$ is a constant. I don't know how to deal with to find $y(x)$ and the $\int y(x)dx$ is well defined since the function is continuous differentiable (we need the continuouity)...Has anybody dealt with this d.e.

Comment: @Nav89 from the original DE you posted factorize $y'$ then you have $y'(......)=0$ this gives you two solutions

Comment: $-xy^{'}(x)+\alpha y^{'}(x)-\beta y(x) y^{'}(x)=0 \implies (-x+\alpha -\beta y(x) )y^{'}(x)=0$ then use the fact that $AB=0 \implies A=0 $  or $B=0$ @Nav89

Comment: You have the one solution that is constant, that is 
$$y(x)=C$$ from the derivative that equals zero and the second comes immediately and is
$$y(x)=\frac{x-\alpha}{\beta}$$

Comment: Ohh...thank you! Both of ya! I just thought it was more complex...pfff

Comment: @Nav89 you're welcome ....

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Rewrite as

$$\alpha y'(x)-\frac\beta2 (y^2(x))'-(xy(x))'=0$$ and integrate.